# RPGLE Dynamic SQL with Select clause does not work

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, rpgle

After reading several articles about SQLRPGLE and retrieving data and storing them in data structure arrays, I came up with dynamic sql statements.

This works fine as long as I am using these dynamic to-replace fields for my where condition. But as soo as I am using these ? parameter in the select part, or in general as replacement for database fields, the result is blank.

Here is the DDS definition and the program:

> TESTPF

```
A**************************************************************************
A*
A*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
A*
A          R TESTPFR
A
A            FLD01          2S 0
A            FLD02         20A
A
A**************************************************************************
```

I have already filled this file with some dummy data. Here is what's inside:

> runqry () qtemp/testpf

```
       FLD01  FLD02   
000001    1   Text 01 
000002    2   Text 02 
000003    3   Text 03 
000004    4   Text 04 
000005    5   Text 05 
000006    6   Text 06 
000007    7   Text 07 
000008    8   Text 08 
000009    9   Text 09 
000010   10   Text 10
```

And this is the program:

> TST001I

```
 D**********************************************************************************************
 D*  Standalone Fields
 D*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 D stm             s            500a   inz(*blanks)
 D fieldName01     s             10a   inz(*blanks)
 D fieldName02     s             10a   inz(*blanks)
 D fieldName03     s              2a   inz(*blanks)
 D text            s             20a   inz(*blanks)
 D
 C**********************************************************************************************
 C*  M A I N   P R O G R A M M
 C**********************************************************************************************

   stm = 'SELECT fld02 FROM testpf WHERE fld01 = 1';
   exec sql prepare s1 from :stm;
   exec sql declare c1 cursor for s1;
   exec sql open c1;
   exec sql fetch c1 into :text;
   exec sql close c1;
   dsply text;   // Prints 'Text 01'
   text = *blanks;

   stm = 'SELECT fld02 FROM testpf WHERE fld01 = ?';
   exec sql prepare s2 from :stm;
   exec sql declare c2 cursor for s2;
   fieldName03 = '2';
   exec sql open c2 using :fieldName03;
   exec sql fetch c2 into :text;
   exec sql close c2;
   dsply text;   // Prints 'Text 02'
   text = *blanks;

   stm = 'SELECT ? FROM testpf WHERE fld01 = 3';
   exec sql prepare s3 from :stm;
   exec sql declare c3 cursor for s3;
   fieldName01 = 'FLD02';
   exec sql open c3 using :fieldName01;
   exec sql fetch c3 into :text;
   exec sql close c3;
   dsply text;   // Prints ' '
   text = *blanks;

   stm = 'SELECT ? FROM testpf WHERE ? = ?';
   exec sql prepare s4 from :stm;
   exec sql declare c4 cursor for s4;
   fieldName01 = 'FLD02';
   fieldName02 = 'FLD01';
   fieldName03 = '4';
   exec sql open c4 using :fieldName01, :fieldName02, :fieldName03;
   exec sql fetch c4 into :text;
   exec sql close c4;
   dsply text;   // Prints ' '
   text = *blanks;

   *inlr = *on;
 C**********************************************************************************************
```

This is the output:

```
DSPLY  Text 01
DSPLY  Text 02
DSPLY         
DSPLY         
DSPLY
```

May someone help me and explain why this is the case?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, show some example code, and maybe someone can help explain it to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a prepared statement, you can use `?` as a parameter marker wherever you can use a host variable in a static statement. Of your four sample prepared statements, the first 3 should work, though the third one will not return what you seem to expect as it is equivalent to:

```
SELECT 'FLD02' FROM testpf WHERE fld01 = 3
```

I would expect to receive the value `'FLD02'` as the result, not the value in column FLD02. This is because the `?` is not a string replacement marker, but a parameter field marker. You can't use it to select a column, but you can use it to provide a value for comparisons, or a constant to be output.

The fourth sample is valid SQL, but it is equivalent to:

```
SELECT 'FLD02' FROM testpf WHERE 'FLD01' = '4'
```

This will return nothing since `'FLD01'` does not equal `'4'`.

Another consequence of this is that the `?` can be used to provide a numeric value to the prepared statement. So you can do this:

```
dcl-s seqno   Packed(5:0);

exec sql declare c2 cursor for s2;

stm = 'SELECT fld02 FROM testpf WHERE fld01 = ?';
exec sql prepare s2 from :stm;
seqno = 2;
exec sql open c2 using :seqno;
```

Also notice that I removed the declaration of the cursor to somewhere outside the logic flow as the declaration is not an executable statement. I see programs where the declare is in a subroutine that is called before a separate subroutine containing the open for the cursor. This is semantically incorrect. The `DECLARE CURSOR` statement is more correctly equivalent to an RPGLE `dcl-` statement. But because the SQL precompiler processes the source linearly, largely without regard to subroutines or sub-procedures, the requirement is for the `DECLARE CURSOR` to be physically before the `OPEN` in the source.

Generally I like to put my SQL Declares at the head of the program right after the `SET OPTION` statement which must be the first SQL embedded in the program. This is where I put the declares when I am using prepared statements. I also declare the statement name as well though this isn't strictly necessary. There is a little gotcha for this though, and that exists when using static SQL with locally scoped host variables. To deal with this, I declare static cursors a bit differently when using sub-procedures. The SQL precompiler recognizes that sub-procedures use locally scoped variables, so if you are declaring a static cursor with locally scoped host variables, the host variables and the cursor declaration must be in the same scope. That means I must declare my static cursors in the same sub-procedure as the open. I still declare the cursor up near the RPGLE `dcl-` statements to keep the declarations together.